# How can I map null namespace to a specific package?

Tags: maven, jaxb, xml-namespaces, xjc

I'm trying to compile a bunch of XSDs using `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin`.

I mapped namespaces to packages like this.

```xml
<jaxb:bindings namespace="urn:some:a" schemaLocation="../xsd/a.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
      <jaxb:package name="some.a"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
<jaxb:bindings namespace="urn:some:b" schemaLocation="../xsd/b.xsd">
  <jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:package name="some.b"/>
  </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

The problem is `c.xsd` is not in any namespace. It actually compiles into `generated` package.

I treid,

```xml
<jaxb:bindings namespace="" schemaLocation="../xsd/c.xsd">
  <jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:package name="some"/>
  </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

and it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

---

**Update**

Woo, xjc tool doc is saying...

> If no `targetNamespace` is declared, then use a hard coded package named `generated`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Woo, xjc tool doc is saying...
>
> > If no `targetNamespace` is declared, then use a hard coded package named `generated`.

Only if it's not customized with `jaxb:package`, see [com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ClassSelector](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/de2ac07156926d062017fa4845184fd16f4b88dd/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/ClassSelector.java#L469-L471).

Actually, the following customization should work:

```xml
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/c.xsd">
  <jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <jaxb:package name="some"/>
  </jaxb:schemaBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

You don't need `namespace` on `jaxb:bindings`.

Here's a [test project](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/tree/master/tests/p%20o) which [demonstrates exactly that](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/master/tests/p%20o/src/main/resources/binding.xjb#L4-L8).

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin).